Create a Custom Keying Set
I would like to create my own custom keying set that only has specific channels for bones of my choosing plus custom properties like ik/fk switches. I want to use this to create key poses and for auto-keying when editing later. Workflow as follows:

pose character
use "i" in the viewport to set keyframes on my custom key set
repeat for other key poses

I would also like to know how to group the channels so they are organized nicely in the Action Editor. The "Whole Character" built in keying set has this grouping enabled. I don't want to use the "Whole Character" built in keying set as it keys channels I'm not interested in keying such as scale.
Thanks!
